# Explicit inverse for the isomorphism induced by a non degenerate pairing?

Tags: linear-algebra

As we all know, for finite-dimensional vectors spaces, a non degenerate bilinear form $\omega:V \times W \to F$ induces an isomorphism $\phi:V \to W^*$ given by $\phi(v) = \omega(v,-).$ However, one usually proves this indirectly by a dimensional argument. My question is: is it possible to find an explicit inverse to $\phi?$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose $V = \mathbb K^m$ and $W = \mathbb K^n$, where $\mathbb K$ is the underlying field.

Write $\omega(v,w) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} v_i w_j $.  If $\omega$ is non-degenerate, then the matrix $A$ is invertible.  In particular, $m = n$.

Now let $\phi(v) = (\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij} v_i)_{1 \le j \le n} = A^T v$.  Since the matrix $A$ is invertible, so is $A^T$, and hence $\phi$ is invertible.  And the inverse of $\phi$ is given by the matrix $(A^T)^{-1}$.